# Array or Object what is it?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, object

I have a Variable called `$account['access_token']`.

It has some items and looks like this when I print it:

`{"access_token":"XXXXX","token_type":"Bearer"}`

I want to print the "XXXXX". I already tryed :

`$account['access_token']['access_token']`
and:
`$account['access_token']->access_token`

but it doesnt work correctly. How do i get the XXXXX?

Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Tip: get used to how PHP outputs data. Try `var_dump(array('foo' => 'bar'))`, `echo array()`, `var_dump(new stdClass)`, `echo new stdClass`. If your data looks different, it's not an array or object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `$account['access_token']` variable looks like it's a JSON string. Try using [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to read the variables from it.

### Example:

```
$obj = json_decode( $account['access_token'] );
var_dump( $obj->access_token );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$obj = json_decode($account['access_token']);
var_dump($obj->access_token);
```

or

```
$assoc = json_decode($account['access_token'], true);
var_dump($assoc['access_token']);
```